# how to use special character in prepared statement java

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

im not so frequent user of like clause, but now i have requirement i want fetch some files based on it name .
 i tried with

```
"SELECT *  FROM FILES WHERE FILENAME LIKE "+"%"+"?"+"%";
```

next i tried with escaping the character

```
 "SELECT *  FROM FILES WHERE FILENAME LIKE "+"\\%"+"?"+"\\%";
```

both the ways when i create prepared statement and execute its giving error ,

please help me how can i use % ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the error message. How else can we know what's going wrong?

Comment: Did you try `"SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE FILENAME LIKE '%?%'"` ? **EDIT** Notice the ' character

Comment: this is the error messageMessage 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'co'%' at line 1'
2013-02-21 18:51:47,445 ERROR [STDERR] com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'co'%' at line 1

Comment: Its not valid syntax because the prepared statement will substitute the ? with 'paramValue' (Including the quotes). hence the % has to be inside the parameter value

Comment: yes i tried Did you try "SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE FILENAME LIKE '%?%'"  even that gives a error tht no of parameters required is 0 so its not detecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with cowls answer, but I think you also want a percent sign after the search string, based on your initial post.

So, something like:

```
"%myfilename%"
```

Answer (score 5):

Just do this:

```
"SELECT *  FROM FILES WHERE FILENAME LIKE ?";
```

Then pass the parameter through as

```
"%.jpg"
```

Or use whatever wildcards you desire.

E.g.

```
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT *  FROM FILES WHERE FILENAME LIKE ?");
st.setString(1, "%.jpg");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```